Как анимировать плавную смену цвета градиента при смене темы со светлой на темную и наоборот?
Необходимо реализовать плавную смену цвета градиента при смене темы с темной на светлую и наоборот на СSS
:root.theme-dark {
--background-image:  repeating-linear-gradient(
  to bottom,
  #000000 0px 2px ,
  #00000000 2px 4px
),
repeating-linear-gradient(
  to left,
  #000000 0px 2px ,
  #00000000 2px 4px
),
linear-gradient(to bottom, #007f0c 0.01%, #004306);
}


:root.theme-light{
    --background-image:  repeating-linear-gradient(
  to bottom,
  #d3d3d3 0px 2px ,
  #d3d3d300 2px 4px
),
repeating-linear-gradient(
  to left,
  #d3d3d3 0px 2px ,
  #d3d3d300 2px 4px
),
linear-gradient(to bottom, #e7e7e7 0.01%, #1a1a1a);
}

.page{
 background-color: var(--background-color);
 }


Через анимацию переменных с цветами.
